# Are the solutions to the equation $f(n \cdot x)=x$ always expressible in closed form?

Tags: functions

Are the solutions to the equation:

$$f(n \cdot x)=x$$

always expressible in closed form?

$$n=1,2,3,4,5,...$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you mean by closed form, but if you mean in terms of elementary functions, then no. Consider, for instance, $f(x) = e^x-2$. There is no closed form for $n=1$ much less the other values of $n$.

Comment: $e^x = x$ has no solutions.  Perhaps you want to consider $e^x - 4$ or something.

Comment: @Goos Great point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"Closed form" means i.a. that the set of the allowed functions is given.

$$f(n\cdot x)=x\ \ \ \ \ (n\in\mathbb{N}_+)\tag{1}$$

There are [addition theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_theorem) for some kinds of functions $f$, e.g. for the exponential functions, the trigonometric functions, the hyperbolic functions, the spherical harmonics and the elliptic functions.

Maybe this is interesting:
[Ritt, J. F.: Periodic functions with a multiplication theorem. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 23 (1922) (1) 16-25](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1922-023-01/S0002-9947-1922-1501186-3/)

If $f$ is an algebraic function, Galois theory says which kinds of equation 1 have solutions that are radicals (or elementary numbers). But all solutions of equation 1 can be represented by special functions like elliptic functions, Bring radicals and/or theta functions then.
see e.g.:
[closed-form expression for roots of a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291909/closed-form-expression-for-roots-of-a-polynomial/4229838#4229838)
[How do you solve 5th degree polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555743/how-do-you-solve-5th-degree-polynomials/4229237#4229237)

If $f$ is a transcendental function, equation 1 can have algebraic solutions only at the [exceptional points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function#Exceptional_set) of $f(n\cdot x)$.
see e.g. [On the behavior of transcendental functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000638/on-the-behavior-of-transcendental-functions/3889240#3889240)

If $f(n\cdot x)$ is a transcendental expression of $x$ over a non-discrete multi-element domain, $f(n\cdot x)-x$ doesn't have a partial inverse over a non-discrete domain that is an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

If $f=\exp$, equation 1 doesn't have solutions that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number), but it has solutions in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

see e.g.:
[Example equation which does not have a closed-form solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644370/example-equation-which-does-not-have-a-closed-form-solution/4219932#4219932)
[Is there an algorithm to determine if a closed-form solution exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467667/is-there-an-algorithm-to-determine-if-a-closed-form-solution-exists/4138049#4138049)