# Solving the geometric series for q

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials, roots

Is there a general way to find the $q > 0$ solving the equation from the geometric series $$1+q+q^2+q^3+\ldots + q^n = a$$ or $$\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q} = a\quad\text{with } q \neq 1$$ for $a > 1$ and $n\in\mathbb N$?

---

*My thoughts:* Since polynomials aren't solvable in general for degree 5 or higher, I guess the above equation has no explicit solution for $n\ge 5$. In this case [numerical approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) can be used. For $n=5$ also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1557660/32951) method can be used.

Comment: It is easier to solve $\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}=a$

Comment: Newton's method is often used for this case. For $a$ close to $1$, $q\approx a-1$ and for $a\gg1$, $q\approx\sqrt[n]a$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $q\approx1-1/a$, not $1-a$.

Comment: For a numerical method, I wrote $a(q-1) = q^{n-1} - 1 = \int_1^q (n+1)x^n \; dx$ and then chose a $k$ and approximated the integral with trapezoid or Simpson's rule.  I ended up with $a(q-1) \approx (n+1)q^{n+1}F(k)/3k^{n+1}$.  Where $F(k)$ is not that hard to work out once $k$ is chosen.  This near equation is only slightly easier to solve than the original, but I offer my thoughts.

Comment: You can find a series solution here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9411224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-arrange 
\begin{align*}
  q &= \frac{a-1}{a-q^n} \\
    &= \frac{a-1}{a-\left(\frac{a-1}{a-q^n}\right)^n} \\
    &= \frac{a-1}
            {a-\left(
                 \frac{a-1}
                      {a-\left(
                           \frac{a-1}{a-\ddots}
                         \right)^n}
               \right)^n} \\
   &= \frac{a-1}{a}
      \left \{
        1+\frac{(a-1)^n}{a^{n+1}}+\ldots+
        \frac{(nk+k)!}{k! (nk+1)!}
        \left[ \frac{(a-1)^n}{a^{n+1}} \right]^{k}+\ldots
      \right \}
\end{align*}

> Lagrange inversion formula
>
> \begin{align*}
>  f(q) &= aq-q^{n+1} \\
>  q &= f^{-1}(a-1) \\
>  &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i!} \frac{d^{i-1}}{dx^{i-1}} \left. \left(\frac{x-0}{f(x)-f(0)} \right)^{i} \right|_{x=0} [(a-1)-f(0)]^{i} \\
>  &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i!} \frac{d^{i-1}}{dx^{i-1}} \left. \left(\frac{1}{a-x^{n}} \right)^{i} \right|_{x=0} (a-1)^{i}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Can you better explain your last equivalence. It seems interessino but I can't see how to make it general.

Comment: $$q=\frac{a-1}{a}+\delta=\frac{a-1}{a-\left( \frac{a-1}{a}+\delta \right)^{n}} \implies \frac{a-1}{a}+\delta=\frac{a-1}{a} \left[ 1+\frac{1}{a}\left( \frac{a-1}{a}+\delta \right)^{n}+\ldots \right] $$$$\implies \delta \approx \frac{(a-1)^{n+1}}{a^{n+2}}$$ and repeat in similar manner to obtain higher order terms.

Comment: See also [Lagrange Inversion Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Example)