# Solving equation of degree 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

Find all real values of $x$ such that
$$x^2+1=2\sqrt[3]{2x-1}.$$
Let $t=\sqrt[3]{2x-1}$. Then the equation is equivalent to
$$\left(\frac{t^3+1}{2}\right)^2+1-2t=0 \Leftrightarrow t^6+2t^3-8t+5=0 \Leftrightarrow \left(t-1\right)\left(t^5+t^4+t^3+3t^2+3t-5\right)=0$$
I cannot handle the equation of degree $5$. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is an error in your computation. A quick check using WolframAlpha gave https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+t%5E5%2Bt%5E4%2Bt%5E3%2B3t%5E2%2B3t-5 as solutions for the polynomial whereas the original equation https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E2%2B1%3D2*(2x-1)%5E(1%2F3)+for+x admits only two solutions.

Comment: This equation is from AOPS?

Comment: Note $x=1$ is a solution

Comment: We all know this from above!

Comment: It has 2 root, 1 and 0.716. But I a want an explicit formula of the root 0.7168

Answer (score 1):

Taking everything to the third power gives $$(x^2+1)^3=2^3(2x-1)$$ that is $$x^6+3x^4+3x^2+1=16x-8,$$ i.e. we are searching for roots of $$x^6+3x^4+3x^2-16x+9=0.$$ Since the sum over all of the coefficients is zero, $x=1$ is a root. Polynomial division gives that the other solutions are the roots of $$x^5+x^4+4x^3+4x^2+7x-9.$$ You get four complex roots and another real root that you can calculate using a computer algebra system such was WolframAlpha.

Comment: Can you have an explicit representation of the root?

Comment: You can but in general won't have an explicit formula for the roots of a degree five polynomial. That's the statement of the Abel-Ruffini theorem. For a discussion see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555743/how-do-you-solve-5th-degree-polynomials

Comment: The decimal approximation for the remaining real root is 0.71683662408618024174708229 if that helps you.