# Do smooth "almost-algebraic" transcendental curves exist?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-curves, transcendental-numbers, transcendental-functions

Is it possible for a smooth, transcendental plane curve to be such that for *every* point $(a,b)$ on the curve, there is a polynomial with rational coefficients $p(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ where $p(a,b)=0$? The curve $y=e^x$ is *not* such a curve, because $\pi$ and $e^\pi$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, so there is no polynomial in $Q[x,y]$ of which $(\pi, e^\pi)$ is a zero.

Equivalently: is there a smooth, transcendental plane curve $C$ such that, given any point $(a,b)$ on the curve, there is an algebraic curve which intersects $C$ at $(a,b)$?

Comment: Does "smooth" mean continuously differentiable or infinitely differentiable or something else? The first two are the most commonly used meanings, although sometimes neither is meant (another meaning that I'm familiar with is used in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-12/issue-1/Smooth-functions/10.1215/S0012-7094-45-01206-3.short) and [this other paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01958022) and in a few other publications).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I meant infinitely differentiable. To be very informal, a "nice" curve would do, I don't want a really pathological example.

Comment: Possibly relevant is IV_'s answer to [On the behavior of transcendental functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3889240/13130) **AND** [*Some transcendental curves and numbers*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03016038) by Bauer/Slobin (1913) **AND** [*Algebraic and transcendental numbers*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03015200) by Bauer/Slobin (1914) **AND** [*A certain class of transcendental curves*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03015977) by Allen (1915) **(continued)**

Comment: **AND** the Masters thesis [**Transcendentalism of Curves and of Numbers**](https://mospace.umsystem.edu/xmlui/handle/10355/49197) by Hughes (1916) **AND** [*A system of algebraic and transcendental equations*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2972041) by Bauer/Slobin (1918). In case you don't have access the 3 papers published in **Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo**, I have .pdf scan copies of photocopies I made 10-15 years ago.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: [*Algebraic and transcendental solutions of some exceptional equations*](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.187.1621&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Sondow/Marques (2010) **AND** [*Schanuel's conjecture and algebraic powers* $z^w$ *and* $w^z$ *with* $z$ *and* $w$ *transcendental*](http://eastwestmath.org/index.php/ewm/article/view/138) by Marques/Sondow (2010).

Comment: Thanks for the references, I'll look through them.